# Плавно растянуть div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

в контейнер **div** с классом **.message** добавляется другие **div** по средствам **ajax**
как сделать что бы при добавлении новых элементов контейнер **.message**
плавно растягивался по высоте контента ?

Comment: задать для вставляемых блоков в стилях `display:none`, а непосредственно после загрузки делать `.slideDown()`

Comment: да спасибо работает !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У свойства `height` исходное значение `auto`, поэтому `transition: height` с ним не работает.
Следовательно, самое разумное и очевидное решение - устанавливать значение свойства `height` явно: при вставке контента в контейнер (получая либо высоту контента, либо высоту контейнера после вставки).

Пример реализации второго способа (ресайз после вставки, по суммарной высоте):

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');
updateHeight(container);  // изначальная установка высоты в пикселях
let count = 5,
    interval = setInterval(() => {  // добавление 5 блоков с интервалом 1с
      if (!count) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }
      container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="content-block"></div>');
      updateHeight(container);     // добавили контент - изменим высоту контейнера
      count--;
    }, 1000);

// считает высоту элемента по принципу "scrollHeight минус паддинги"
function updateHeight(el) {
  let cs = getComputedStyle(el),
      paddings = (parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('padding-top'))    || 0) + 
                 (parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom')) || 0);
  el.style.height = (el.scrollHeight - paddings) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#container {
  border : 1px dashed red;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  color: red;
  overflow-y: hidden;  /* обязательно */
  transition: height 0.2s linear;
}

.content-block {
  height: 1em;  /* явно указывать высоту потомков не обязательно, здесь это делается только потому что div'ы добавляются пустыми (мне лень копипастить lorem ipsum) */
  margin: 8px;
  background: #77d;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Контейнер</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[вот это вы имеете ввиду jquery::animate?](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

и поясните что такое по высоте - по высоте последнего вставленного div ?

Comment: по высоте всех вставленных div

Comment: вы вставляете див в див?

Comment: да динамически  вставляю

Comment: А в чем сложность возникает? у блока стиль  height: auto; и все должно быть в ажуре. https://jsfiddle.net/8thag4ze/

Comment: height: auto не работает а работает только с единицами измерения а откуда узнать height блока если он еще не прибыл )

Comment: может быть тогда у .message указать фиксированную ширину и overflow: auto? https://jsfiddle.net/cerxcfu6/